# Extracting a specific string from a long xml string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

The text i' interested in .

I need to get the `Element` description, example:

```
Variable SIM_CARD is does not exist in BO
```

Please advise on the structure of the query.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><responseRoot requestId="CRM0090506" timeStamp="20120706T174251" status="KO"><errorMessage>E|CRM0090506:33(MOB_EXECUTE/CONFIGURE) Error detected while execution on a Network Element: Variable SIM_CARD is does not exist in BO. fault code: S-SYS-00009 raised for Network Element BKCS_PN_MOB_Type, Technical Product Order MOB_EXECUTE and Command EXECUTE</errorMessage></responseRoot>                                                   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><responseRoot requestId="CRM0085769" timeStamp="20120702T095739" status="KO"><errorMessage>E|CRM0085769:33(MOB_EXECUTE/CONFIGURE) Error detected while execution on a Network Element: OperationFailed-The Basic Subscription subscriber(MCC=639,MNC=07,MSIN=0002517747)does not exist. fault code: 31-10115 raised for Network Element BKCS_PN_MOB_Type, Technical Product Order MOB_EXECUTE and Command EXECUTE</errorMessage></responseRoot>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><responseRoot requestId="CRM0085772" timeStamp="20120702T100120" status="KO"><errorMessage>E|CRM0085772:33(MOB_EXECUTE/CONFIGURE) Error detected while execution on a Network Element: OperationFailed-The Basic Subscription subscriber(MCC=639,MNC=07,MSIN=0002517747)does not exist. fault code: 31-10115 raised for Network Element BKCS_PN_MOB_Type, Technical Product Order MOB_EXECUTE and Command EXECUTE</errorMessage></responseRoot>
```

Comment: The column in the db is called kpsa-Response

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried and what happened when you tried it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help in building your question.

Comment: select regexp_substr ('"Element: Variable SIM_CARD is does not exist in BO.>"', 'Element:*[^[:alnum:]]+...........................................')
from legal.gsm_failed_swaps_log
where kpsa_response != 'null';      The beside query is what i have tried. It returns the message within the quotes which is not helpful because i need for the message to be picked from the db

Comment: Update your question with all the requirements

Answer (score 1):

A *regex* group is needed:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('"Element: Variable SIM_CARD is does not exist in BO.>"',
                     'Element:([^\.]+)',
                     1,
                     1,
                     'i',
                     1)
  FROM DUAL;
```

Having the closing `TAG` as delimiter , to `update`:

```
UPDATE legal.gsm_failed_swaps_log
   SET kpsa_response = REGEXP_SUBSTR(kpsa_response,
                                     'Element:\s*([^<]+)</',
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     'i',
                                     1)
 WHERE ....
```

Check `oracle` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work . Only one slight issue though. Variable SIM_CARD is does not exist in BO is just an example of the various responses in the column. I need to pick all the different responses. what modifications can be made to the query?

Comment: my idea is ..instead of putting a source string directly, we put the column of the database table in place of the source string, like below                              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(kpsa_response,
                     'Element:([^\.]+)',
                     1,
                     1,
                     'i',
                     1)
  FROM legal.gsm_failed_swaps_log;

Comment: Ok, so you need an `UPDATE`..  Do you need the string from `Element` to `???` .. maybe the closing `tag` ? `</errorMessage>`

Comment: i need the string fro element all the way to the first full stop. Mostly after BO but in some other responses its differenr

Comment: From the xml i posted above you can see that on the second and third examples, after element the string is different

Comment: i think i'm drawing closer to the answer. I have been trying out your above solutions.However, kpsa_response which is the name of the column does not seem to populate the source string so it returns null

Comment: Thanks klashxx very much for your help.The below code finally has worked perfectly well             select  
REGEXP_SUBSTR(kpsa_response,
                                    'Element:([^\.]+)',
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     'i',
                                     1)
from
legal.gsm_failed_swaps_log
WHERE kpsa_response != 'null';